# Scroll to supplementary view

Tags: swiftui

I want to scroll to the view above the grid, but this approach doesn't work. I need to support iOS 15+ so I can't use the fancy new API to an achieve this.

What am I doing wrong?

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
        VStack {
            myView
                .tag("Hi")
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(products), id: \.0) { item in
                    ProductCardView(product: item)
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: products) { _ in
            proxy.scrollTo("Hi")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have given the first view a tag of "Hi". But the parameter passed to ```scrollTo``` needs to be an id. So try ```.id("Hi")``` instead.